# Trying to understand the "template <class U> friend class B;" syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, grammar, friend

The following is a simple c++ program that compiles with my MinGW compiler, and executes as expected:

```
#include <iostream>


template <class T> class A {
    T a;
    template <class U> friend class B;

  public:
    A<T> (T t) : a(t) {}
};



template <class T> class B {
   A<T> aa;

  public:

    B<T> (T t) : aa(t) {}

    T getT() const {return aa.a;}
};


int main() {
    B<int> b(5);
    std::cout << "> " << b.getT() << std::endl;
}
```

Since `B<T>::getT()` accesses the *private* `A<T>::a` member, `A<T>` makes `B<T>` a friend with `template <class U> friend class B;` line.

Unfortunately, I don't know *why* this line needs to be written like this. Intuitively, I would have expected something like `friend class B<T>`, yet, this doesn't compile.

The meaning of the newly introduced `U` is unclear as well, since `A`'s and `B`'s dependant type is `T` in both cases.

So, in short, I'd appreciate any light on how the syntax for this line is derived or deduced.

Comment: what's the error if you try `friend class B<T>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many different permutations of friendship and templates.

Your present code makes *any* template specialization of `B` into a friend for `A<T>`, so for example `B<char>` is a friend of `A<int>`.

If you only wanted to make the matching `A<T>` a friend, you would say it like this:

```
template <typename> class B;  // forward declare above!

template <typename T>
class A
{
    // ...

    friend class B<T>;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, `friend class B<T>;` would have worked had you inserted a forward declaration

```
template<class T> class B;
```

before that of `class A<T>`.

The `template <class U> friend class B;` makes every `class B<U>` a friend, not just `class B<T>`.